# Properly handling state and WebSockets in a functional way

Tags: javascript, typescript, server, functional-programming, frp

This is part of a larger project, where I am rewriting the imperative code of my multiplayer game to be functional. Right now, I am more or less at the start, trying to think at a high level about the structure. Here is what I had in mind:

The part that bridges the imperative-functional gap is this class:

```
class MessageStream<T> {
  private readonly actions: T[] = []
  private popResolvers: ((value: T) => void)[] = []

  push(value: T) {
    this.actions.push(value)
    if (this.popResolvers.length > 0) {
      this.popResolvers.shift()(this.actions.shift())
    }
  }

  pop(): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve) => {
      if (this.actions.length > 0 && this.popResolvers.length === 0) {
        resolve(this.actions.shift())
      } else {
        this.popResolvers.push(resolve)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I start the web server like this:

```
const server = new WebServer.Server({ port: 3000 })
const messageStream = new MessageStream<string>()
const initialState: State  = { letters: "a" }

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    try {
      messageStream.push(data.toString())
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("[Error index.ts]", error)
    }
  })
})
```

This is where the state updating logic would go:

```
const handle = async (stream: MessageStream<string>, state: State) => {
  const action = await stream.pop()
  // do some other thinking to update the state, such as:
  handle(stream, { letters: state.letters + action })
}
```

And this is how we link them:

```
handle(messageStream, initialState)
```

Is this the right way to go about writing an FRP-driven server for a multiplayer game? Is the "architecture" here correct? Is there a way to avoid `MessageStream`, or is that the right way to do this? The recursion in `handle` seems a little suspicious (feels like the stack can get huge), but I don't see any other way to avoid a global state.

The other confusing part here is that this structure forces all operations to be processed in sequence. *Nothing* can happen concurrently. But what if processing a message was an intensive operation that I wanted to parallelize, and I only wanted to synchronize updating the state? How, structurally, would one go about doing that?

#### Edit

Here is a rewrite of `handle` to be more like `reduce`:

```
const reduce = async (
  stream: MessageStream<Action>,
  callbackfn: (
    state: State,
    action: Action
  ) => { newState: State; sideEffects: SideEffect[] },
  initialState: State,
  executeSideEffect: (sideEffect: SideEffect) => void
) => {
  let state = initialState
  while (true) {
    const action = await stream.pop()
    const { newState, sideEffects } = callbackfn(state, action)
    sideEffects.map(executeSideEffect)
    state = newState
  }
}

// example usage
reduce(
  messageStream,
  (s, a) => ({
    newState: { letters: s.letters + a.addLetter },
    sideEffects: [
      {
        type: SideEffectType.NotifyUser,
        info: `Got your message, ${a.addLetter}!`,
      },
    ],
  }),
  { letters: "a" },
  (e) => console.log(e)
)
```

Then, in `socket.on("message")`, we push the action to `messageStream` like above. This way, all the non-pure behavior is contained to the top level of the `reduce` function. However, one potential anti-pattern is that `reduce` never returns anything. Is that bad?

Comment: To avoid the recursion, you can just write `while (true) { state = { letters: state.letters + await stream.pop() }; }`.

Comment: In "true" FRP you wouldn't ever "iterate" a stream, you'd only transform it into something else, e.g. with `.reduce()` - but yeah in the end you always need some imperative-looking part that actually *runs* the program. Notice that promises are effectful and not pure, I'd avoid them on the business logic layer.

Comment: Imperative style of code is sometimes more performant, keeping a list of global compared to passing around many variables as arguments and closures. Why go functional in a video game?

Comment: @IsaakEriksson Because immutable data structures are sometimes more performant? And definitely make some things easier. Why not go functional?

Comment: @Bergi if I replace the recursion with a while loop, then I must have a mutable variable, maybe in  `handle`. But at that point, isn't it even cleaner to refactor like this: (1) Get rid of `MessageStream`; (2) make a mutable, global state; (3) and in `socket.on("message")` directly call `handle`, passing in the message and state? The downsides are that this is imperative and we have a global mutated state.

Comment: @Daniel A *local* mutable variable is fine, it does not have the problems of global mutable state. My point was that it's really equivalent to the recursion (but possibly more efficient in terms of stack space). What I would suggest, if you want to continue with this design, is to write a `reduce` function that you can use like `reduce(messageStream, (state, action) => ({ letters: state.letters + action }), initialState)`. How exactly `reduce` pulls data from the stream (or is getting pushed), and whether that happens iteratively or recursively, does not matter.

Comment: @Daniel However, the *actual* problem to solve is what would the return value of such a `reduce` function be? Your current `handle` function does return nothing, so the entire call could just be dropped without altering the behaviour of your program if it really is pure. Or would the handler produce some effects? If yes, how, and how to keep them pure according to FRP principles?

Comment: @Bergi I added an edit to the bottom of the post incorporating your suggestion. Is it more proper now, or am I using some anti-pattern?

Comment: Thanks, much better! Now if you incorporate a way to get the results from the effects back into the reducer, you almost got the [ELM architecture](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/) :-)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for all your help! Those side effects are going to be sending messages through the web socket to the client (a mobile app). When you say, "get the results... back into the reducer," you're basically referring to client-code, right? Or do you mean adding more logic to the reducer/server?

Comment: Really, sending messages on the web socket is the only effect that this reducer would do? No communication with other streams, no database calls, no interaction with shared application state? I would indeed expect there to be more logic.